# bxslider remove gap between slides and thumbnail pager

Tags: css, thumbnails, bxslider

I am using bxslider with a thumbnail pager. It all works fine, but there is a large space between the slides and the thumbnails (about an inch). I can't find where to reduce the size of this gap. Here's my code

```
<div style="width:720px;margin:0 auto;">
<div class="bxslider">
<div style="background-image:url('images/slide14.png');width:710px;height:230px">number 1</div>
<div style="background-image:url('images/slide16.png');width:710px;height:230px">number 2</div>
<div style="background-image:url('images/slide17.png');width:710px;height:230px">number 3</div>
</div>

<div id="bx-pager" style="text-align:center;;">
<a data-slide-index="0" href=""><img src="images/green.png" /></a>
<a data-slide-index="1" href=""><img src="images/purple.png" /></a>
<a data-slide-index="2" href=""><img src="images/blue.png" /></a>
</div>
</div>

<script>
$('.bxslider').bxSlider({
pagerCustom: '#bx-pager'
});
</script>
```

Here's a screenshot - https://i.stack.imgur.com/tjElW.png

Any ideas how I can bring the thumbnails up closer to the slides? Thanks in advance

Comment: A `JSFiddle` would be much helpful meanwhile check may be `margin` of the `class=bx-wrapper` will be causing the issue.

Comment: No idea without your CSS

Comment: Hi Vivekkupadhyay.
Thanks for the advice.
I found this in the CSS

    .bx-wrapper {
     position: relative;
 margin: 0 auto 60px;
 padding: 0;
 *zoom: 1;
    }

I changed the 60px to 20px and that did it

I don't seem to be able to add 1 to your reputation but thanks again

Comment: @Joel  Its okay, you got your solution viz more important :)