# How to fix the gap between slide and thumbnail in bxslider

Tags: asp.net-mvc, bxslider

I have bxslider in my MVC 5 application.

There is a slideshow to display image and there is a list of thumbnail right below the slides.

Right now, there is a gap between the slide and the thumbnails as shown in the picture. [image: Gap]

I read this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32008969/bxslider-remove-gap-between-slides-and-thumbnail-pager) and applied the solution by changing the margin as said in the .bx-wrapper class in the css file. The fix immediately adjust the gap .... but this doesn't stay the same after I refresh the page. As soon as I refresh the page, the gap become big again just like how it was in the original state.

Please help me what is wrong.

My current .bx-wrapper class is like this:

```css
.bx-wrapper {
 position: relative;
 margin: 0 auto 5px; /*control the gap between slider and thumbnail*/
 padding: 0;
 *zoom: 1;
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

What I think is happening is when bxSlider is loading, it applies some of it's CSS directly on the elements. Inline styles override almost any type of styles (exception being `!important`). One way to counteract that behavior is to apply inline style after bxSlider is loaded by the callback [`onSliderLoad`](http://bxslider.com/options#onSliderLoad).

**SNIPPET**

```js
var bx = $('.bx').bxSlider({
  onSliderLoad: adjust,
  pagerCustom: '.bx-nav'
});

function adjust(current) {
  var bxw = document.querySelector('.bx-wrapper');
  bxw.style.marginBottom = 0;
}
```

```css
img {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

nav {
  margin: 0 auto;
  display:table;
}
```

```html
<link href='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/bxslider/4.2.5/jquery.bxslider.css' rel='stylesheet'>


<ul class='bx'>
  <li class='slide'>
    <img src='http://placehold.it/250x150/000/fff?text=1'></li>
  <li class='slide'>
    <img src='http://placehold.it/250x150/00f/eee?text=2'></li>
  <li class='slide'>
    <img src='http://placehold.it/250x150/0e0/111?text=3'></li>

</ul>

<nav class="bx-nav">
  <a data-slide-index="0" href="#/">
    <img src='http://placehold.it/50x50/000/fff?text=1'></a>
  <a data-slide-index="1" href="#/">
    <img src='http://placehold.it/50x50/00f/eee?text=2'></a>
  <a data-slide-index="2" href="#/">
    <img src='http://placehold.it/50x50/0e0/111?text=3'></a>
</nav>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/bxslider/4.2.5/jquery.bxslider.min.js'></script>
```